# Custom upload directory for each file only for current plugin

Tags: uploads

I have a custom plugin to add project documents in my Wordpress site. Now these documents should be stored in their respective project folder such as:

```
EN001/Document1.pdf
EN001/Document2.pdf
EN001/Document3.pdf
EN002/Document1.pdf
EN002/Document2.pdf
```

Documents meta data is stored in a custom table and is given through an API, which is not the question.

Let say I am given following document and meta data via an API POST.

```
[    
    {
        "project":"EN001",
        "file": {
           "file":"file1.pdf",
           "type":"application/pdf"
        }
    },
    {
         "project":"EN00123",
         "file": {
             "file":"file12.pdf",
             "type":"application/pdf"
         }
    }
]
```

After I get this data, I want to upload this document under `wp-content/uploads/EN001` directory. Since I wouldn't know the directory name in advance I can't use wp_upload filter to change uploaddirectory.

Is there any way I can change upload directory according to the project I get via the api like above so that

```
wp-content/uploads/EN001/file1.pdf
wp-content/uploads/EN00123/file12.pdf
```

**Update #1:**

The proposed solution doesn't fix my problem because I can't pass the paths per file to the `upload_dir` filter. My problem is each file will be uploaded in the different folder and I want to be able to pass the folder structure for each file where it will be stored.

Comment: @denis.stoyanov it isn't the duplicate and kindly check my update #1 section

Comment: can't you store the files as an array prior to the update with proper html5 markup of the form?

**Edit 1:** Removed the "duplicate" comment